# Image is not showing according to size

Tags: ios, swift, imageview

I just want to show image according to image size if the image height is grater then width then image will show horizentally  or if the width is grater then height then it will show in centre.

I have already tried and I am showing my code. What I am trying ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var profileImagesData:Array<UIImage> = []
        for i in 0..<profileImages.count {

       // for venueImageTemp  in profileImages {
            var statusDict = profileImages[i] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
            var imageUrl = String(format:"%@",statusDict["imageId"] as! CVarArg)
            print(imageUrl)

            if imageUrl.contains("cloudinary.com") {
                let imgNameArr = imageUrl.components(separatedBy: "upload/")
                print(imgNameArr)
                let subFisrtStr = imgNameArr[0]
                print(subFisrtStr)
                let subStr = imgNameArr[1]
                print(subStr)
                let subImgNameArr = subStr.components(separatedBy: "/")
                print(subImgNameArr)
                let subNameStr = subImgNameArr[1]
                print(subNameStr)
                imageUrl = ""

                imageUrl = subFisrtStr + "upload/h_600,w_600/" + subNameStr
                print(imageUrl)

            }

            let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
            print(url)
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in
            let image = UIImage(data: (data)!)
            profileImagesData.append(image!)
        }

        let imageView = CYCImageScrollView(images: profileImagesData, frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height-150), pageColor: UIColor.lightGray, currentPageColor: UIColor.orange)
//        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)


    }
```

I just want to show image according to their sizes.

Comment: where exactly you are trying to set it in any orientation? where do you want to do that? what is CYCImageScrollView? you can adjust that inside this class?

Answer (score 0):

Use content mode scaleAspectFill instead of scaleAspectFit

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```